# IMacros Checking And Setting Array Element

Tags: javascript, imacros

I'm writing a code in IMacros java-script. The whole code is placed inside a loop.

There is a defined array of 2 elements `myArray[0]` and `myArray[1]`.

The goal is to:

1) Check `if myArray[0] > myArray[1]`

2) If True `myArray[0] = 1`

3) Set `first` and `second` variables to `myArray` elements

First I tried to increase the value of `myArray[0]` by `1` (as an integer value) and only solution that worked as it should (without treating array element as string) was `myArray[0]++;`

But it doesn't work by using array element this way here:

```
for (i = 1; i < 2; i++){
   //some code here ...

   if (myArray[0] > myArray[1]){
   myArray[0] = 1; }

   iimSet("first", myArray[0]);
   iimSet("second", myArray[1]);
   //some code here...
   }
```

While `iimSet` part works the `If` part doesn't.

So if at the beginning it was:

```
myArray[0] = 5 
myArray[1] = 4
```

then after executing the code above it should become :

```
myArray[0] = 1 
myArray[1] = 4 
first = 1 
second = 4
```

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Your code must work, nevertheless try the '`if`'-clause like so: `... if (parseInt(myArray[0]) > parseInt(myArray[1])) ...` .

Comment: Thank you @Shugar now it works!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The resulting code now works:

```
for (i = 1; i < 2; i++){
   //some code here ...

   if (parseInt(myArray[0]) > parseInt(myArray[1])){
   myArray[0] = 1; }

   iimSet("first", myArray[0]);
   iimSet("second", myArray[1]);
   //some code here...
   }
```